# SVG is not talking FULL 'width' of container

Tags: css, svg, styling, google-web-designer

I am trying to make my svg full with width of the screen (container) but its not working. Could someone help me - please?

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 320" preserveAspectRatio="none" class="first-svg">
        <path fill="#27187F" fill-opacity="1" d="M0,192L60,170.7C120,149,240,107,360,106.7C480,107,600,149,720,170.7C840,192,960,192,1080,170.7C1200,149,1320,107,1380,85.3L1440,64L1440,320L1380,320C1320,320,1200,320,1080,320C960,320,840,320,720,320C600,320,480,320,360,320C240,320,120,320,60,320L0,320Z"></path>
    </svg>
```

css

```
.first-svg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    
}
```

[image]

Comment: I suppose you will need to [reset](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css) or [normalize](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/7.0.0/normalize.css) the CSS

Comment: Are you sure there is no margin or padding? Try * {margin:0; padding:0;} We need more code, could you upload minimal reproducible example?

Answer (score 0):

I am suing bootstrap for this project I am working (only for practice)

I have done the following and it seemed to work - I added the SVG inside a row.

```
<div class="row">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 320" preserveAspectRatio="none" class="first-svg">
        <path fill="#27187F" fill-opacity="1" d="M0,192L60,170.7C120,149,240,107,360,106.7C480,107,600,149,720,170.7C840,192,960,192,1080,170.7C1200,149,1320,107,1380,85.3L1440,64L1440,320L1380,320C1320,320,1200,320,1080,320C960,320,840,320,720,320C600,320,480,320,360,320C240,320,120,320,60,320L0,320Z"></path>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Yep that will work because the bootstrap container has padding of 15px on the left and right and rows have -15px margin to counter that. Normally how I would handle this is to add the content to the section give it top and bottom padding of say 75-100px and then use the svg as a background-image in CSS